# Visual Studio 2015 restore package in Bower does nothing

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In Visual Studio 2015, I've added, for example, "angular" as a dependency in bower.json. When I go into Dependencies -> Bower I see angular in the list except it says not installed next to it. Right-clicking on Bower and clicking "Restore packages" removes the "not installed" next to angular, however I don't actually have any angular files added to my wwwroot. Am I missing an extra step here?

Comment: For whatever reason, restarting Visual Studio makes the files get added to my lib folder

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this tomorrow. Are you on beta 2?

Answer (score 7):

Thomas is correct! I ran into the same problem and found that you need to use your Grunt File to run the Bower task. For example, right-click on your Grunt file and choose **Task Runner Explorer**

[image: Task Runner Explorer]

Next, right-click on the **Bower** task and Run.

[image: Run bower]

Once the task is finished running, you will notice the packages have been copied to your wwwroot.

Comment: To save manual running, bind to a Visual Studio event: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-grunt.html#binding-to-visual-studio-events

Comment: I don't have grunt i have gulp and no bower task. What can I do?

Comment: 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  when i run task on bower

Answer (score 6):

The package files are installed into a folder called "bower_components" in your project directory.  The folder is hidden in the Visual Studio solution explorer.  It's meant to be a cache of downloaded package files.

Typically you would setup grunt or gulp tasks to copy or process only the files you need from the package to somewhere under wwwroot.

For example if you install bootstrap using bower you might setup a task to compile and concat the LESS source files with your app's LESS files, or alternatively you might just setup a task to copy the pre-compiled .css files from the bower_components\bootstrap\dest folder.

This post shows how to use bower and grunt together. 
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 2):

On vs 2015 go >**Tools**>**Options**>**Projects and Solutions**>**External Web Tools**
Make sure **$(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git** checked
If you didn't find it, add it

:) close vs2015 n open it, then restoring process will success

Answer (score 2):

Those who are having trouble to use bower in ASP.NET Core 1.0. Please check this out. The problem is due to Git installation path.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902970/4082972

Comment: Thanks!

One day trying to solve things with ASP.Net Core 1.0.

Bypassing version check in the installer...
Reinstalling NuGet...
And now this...

I hope I can start working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, bower packages empty after cloning the solution on a clean machine. Tried right-click sorcery to no avail. The only thing that worked was running bower manually like this (change your VS install path as needed):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\bower.cmd" install -f
```