# bower not working in Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: c#, bower, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, bower-install

I am building a web application in Visual Studio 2015. I am behind corporate proxy. Installing packages via bower is not working.

I tried the following workarounds.

1. Created a .bowerrc file in the solution with the following settings.

   ```
   {
     "proxy": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:Port",
     "https-proxy": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:Port",
     "strict-ssl": false
   }
   ```
2. Installed Git. Changed the git configuration to use https:// instead of git://

When I run the following command
    bower install
I get the following error.

bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads      https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git/':
Failed connect to github.com:443; No error

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Seems your corporate proxy doesn't want you to communicate with github? Verify your proxy settings. The command that fails works fine here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY env var with your proxy settings in order to access git behind a proxy

Comment: 443 error code means https SSL error, did you try to access the url directly may be there's a certificates issue

Comment: I tried to access the url directly from the browser. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Bower in VS2015 CTP. Managed to resolve it by commenting out two lines in the bower.cmd file that is used by VS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605933/3131828.

It basically makes sure that VS uses the Git I had already installed which respects my .gitconfig file. Apparently by default it uses a lightweight git.exe that does not read .gitconfig.