# Visual Studio 2015 bower - not installed

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2015

Using a **Empty Template** in Visual Studio 2015, the following configuration fails to install dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "0.8.0",
    "hammer.js": "2.0.4",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.11.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2"
  }
}
```

**While the same configuration for a Web Application Sample template in ASP.NET completes successfully**.

My colleagues are running into the same problem.

Is this a Known issue? Is there a work around? What am I missing?

Error in the output window is :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
bower bootstrap#3.0.0        ENOTFOUND Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

So I got this error tinkering around the configs again.

ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #128

Comment: Looks like a host not resolved issue: do you have a proxy or something that might be filteri8ng non-interactive HTTP requests?

Comment: @Richard I wish it was. Nopes both the proxy and https-proxy are properly configured. As mentioned above, it works correctly using the "Preview" Template but not with the Empty Template.

Comment: Please check this link. This fixed my problem
[Try reinstalling git with following option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36902970/4082972)

Answer (score 19):

I ran into a similar error in VS 2015 RTM (not RC).
This fixed for me:

1. **Install** git tools (if not already installed) from http://git-scm.com/download/win
2. In the **command line** enter the following command(or git bash if you did not add git to your PATH): *git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://*
3. In VS menu **Tools > Options.. > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools**
4. **Uncheck** $(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
5. **Add** C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin

Hope this helps.

Note: that I experienced this on a MVC 5 web app, not the new preview template but I am using Gulp/Bower/NPM tooling.

**UPDATE 1**
Although not a duplicate scenario the error messages are similar. I wonder if some override is done in the Web Application template somewhere? Would be good to find if thats the case.
[VS 2015 + Bower: Does not work behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725727/vs-2015-bower-does-not-work-behind-firewall#)

**UPDATE 2**
I tried in an empty project after the above changes:
bower bootstrap#3.0.0                      not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.0
bower bootstrap#3.0.0                         resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.0

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it did not help me. Hopefully it will help others who might run into the issue.

Comment: OMG it fixed it!  Well first it caused Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise to crash on me, so I got worried.  After restarting VS2015 back up, it worked perfect.  Thank you deebo, now give back Red's chain! His grandmother gave it to him!  :)

Comment: I'll keep it till Friday ;)

Comment: This one worked for me.  It was really not downloading the packages, not just the bug the other answer mentioned.  After doing this it worked.

Comment: Steps #4 & #5 in isolation cured my "Bower - not installed" issues. +1.

Answer (score 16):

This is a bug.  Expand the wwwroot/lib folder, and it's clear that the packages actually are loaded.  Close/reopen the project, all appears well. We've opened a bug on this from your report.  Thanks for an actionable description of the problem, sorry about the experience.

Comment: I didn't even have to close the project. Just started saving files to get ready to close and it cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

I also run in this problem with VS2015 3 and I did what Owen did but it didn't work for me.

What I did in the end was to

1. delete `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` files
2. delete `bower_components` and `wwwroot` folders.
3. added a new `bower` configuration file to the project
4. added again the dependencies in it.

It worked.

From what I saw in output window before deleting at the end the `wwwroot` folder if you try to add a new bower configuration file VS only installs `bower` if you add a new dependecy and also after that it checks in the `wwwroot` folder that the dependecy files aren't already installed (unfortunatelly I didn't save the output which was saying that it doesnt install the dependecy cause there is already a dependency with same version installed). This means that probablly only deleting `bower_components` and `wwwroot` folder and restoring packages could fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be some bower`s component is not installed. Remove and reinstall this component this via Bower Packege Manager. I had similar situatution after cloning repo. Ng-table lib was not restored and VS show me message in Sulotion Expolrer Bower - Not Installed. This manipulations helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this in VS2015.3. I don't have the time to dig into what is happening to cause the orphanage, but basically the folder under bower_components was identifying as a non-bower folder(?) and preventing bower install from installing the package. (I suspect an issue with VS and TS git repos.)

After trying the tests @deebo listed, I was not any closer. To get this back into a working state I performed the following steps:

1. Delete everything under bower_components
2. Run `bower install` again.

At this point all of my modules installed correctly. I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

Usaly you just need delete bower_components folder in a project and do Bower/Restore Packeges. 
It`is some bower magic.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
{
    "jquery-validation": "1.11.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2"
}
```

just use

```
{
    "jquery-validation": "*",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "*"
}
```

when you use "*" you are telling bower to install any version that is available on the nuGet packages