# ASP.Net MVC 6 Bower Jquery - not installed?

Tags: asp.net, bower, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a project in ASP.Net MVC 6 and I added bower in my project

when I want to use jQuery in my project it some how goes but it give error
in directory

my bower.json file code:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
   "underscore": "~1.8.3",
   "jquery": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

but in directory it give blow error in VS 2015

```
Bower not installed
  jquery - not installed
```

any solutions?

best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 bower - not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654983/visual-studio-2015-bower-not-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was solved when I clicked on Bower and restored it
and rebuild my solution, the error gone away.