# Visual Studio Bower error

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, bower

I'm going through some ASP.NET tutorials and I've encountered an error I don't know how to resolve. I just added a Bower pacakge(?) and Visual Studio (Enterprise 2015) placed it under a **Dependencies** branch. Under that is the **Bower** branch and in that the package appears. Both Dependencies and Bower say "- not installed" after them. I've right-clicked and selected the "Restore" option. Viusal Studio works for a while and then says an error occured. The following error appears in the Output window:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
bower underscore#~1.83      not-cached git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#~1.83
bower underscore#~1.83         resolve git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#~1.83
bower underscore#~1.83         ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git", exit code of #-532462766
```

I'm not terribly familiar with Git, but I know I shouldn't have to have it installed in my workstation. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Can you try moving your project closer to the root of your drive? I suspect you are hitting a MAX_PATH error.

Comment: I checked and I'm not anywhere near the MAX_PATH limitation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No it's not your project that's at max path, but npm nests dependencies recursively and often hits max path errors on package restore. Can you please try moving your project to, say, c:\a\ and try again?

Comment: I moved it to **literally** `c:\a`. It didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: What is the bower package? I'll take a look.

Comment: It is `underscore`, but think Pepto has the answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe bower uses Git client to pull packages directly from GitHub using entries in the packages bower.json file.

Specific to your problem, Git (and therefore bower) is unable to connect to GitHub due to firewall issues. Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725727/vs-2015-bower-does-not-work-behind-firewall)

You can set global git variables (e.g. git config --global xxx) to set proxy etc. to hopefully work around this problem.

According to the error your Git Client is installed locally at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git

Comment: Thanks, Pepto. I'll look into this when I get a chance, but I've just been pulled over into something else that requires all of my time. Will look at ASAP, but may be several weeks. :/

Comment: Lol don't I know that feeling =) Happy coding sir!

Comment: Just awarded you the bounty. If it doesn't actually solve the problem, you gave me a lot to go on! Thanks!