# Cannot install bower packages in my new ASP.NET application

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, bower

I have just created my first asp.net 6 project.

However, whenever I try to install a bower package I get the following error (happens to all packages I attempt to install):

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web
>   Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install Jcrop#2.0.2 --production --force-latest --save bower
>   Jcrop#2.0.2           not-cached
>   https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop.git#2.0.2 bower Jcrop#2.0.2
>   resolve https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop.git#2.0.2 bower Jcrop#2.0.2
>   checkout v2.0.2 bower Jcrop#2.0.2              ECMDERR Failed to
>   execute "git clone https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop.git -b v2.0.2
>   --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #-532462766

I have looked at the thread: 
[VS 2015 + Bower: Does not work behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725727/vs-2015-bower-does-not-work-behind-firewall)

I have tried to disable my firewall and create a .gifconfig file in my user directory containing:

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

But nothing seems to work - I still get the error!

(I don't have git installed, other than what came with Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, what worked for me is to install git from git-scm and have Visual Studio work with that instead of what comes pre-installed.

- Download and install git from https://git-scm.com/downloads/win

  - Note that I needed to exit VS before installation
- Configure VS to use the new version of git

  - In VS Solution Explorer right click on the Bower folder under dependencies and click on 'Configure External Tools...'
  - Uncheck the existing $(DevEnvDir)...\git tool
  - Add a new path to \Program Files\Git\bin
  - Click Ok

Good Luck....

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but I was able to fix it by following the link you provided, but you're missing a critical step: you need to install Git yourself and configure VS to use that instead.