# Error installing bower packages in Visual Studio 2015 for ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core

I am following the migration advice to convert a MVC5 website to a ASP.NET Core website - http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/mvc.html and I am stuck when trying to install the client side packages (Bootstrap and jQuery) using Bower.

I have created an empty ASP.NET 5 Web Application and then I create a bower.json file, but when I save it I get the following in the Output window

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install jquery#2.1.4 --production --force-latest --save
bower jquery#2.1.4          not-cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#2.1.4             resolve https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#2.1.4            checkout 2.1.4
bower jquery#2.1.4             ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git -b 2.1.4 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #-532462766
```

I have also tried using the Bower Package manager inside VS with the same result

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with the ASP.NET Web Tools RC1-update 1

I have seen other posts when this doesn't work (with a different error) but those are when behind a corporate firewall/proxy, which I am not

I am new to this npm/bower stuff. What am I missing?

---

Update:
I ran the commands at a command prompt and it still didn't work, but I do have more detail on the underlying error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'LibGit2Sharp.Branch LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryExtensions.Checkout(LibGit2Sharp.IRepository, LibGit2Sharp.Branch, LibGit2Sharp.Signature)'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.GitCli.GitShim.clone(String url, String workingDirectory, String branchName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.GitCli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

And found this link, where other people seem to be having the same problem https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1322649/bower-cannot-get-packages-with-protocol-git-since-behind-a-firewall

So looks to be an issue where MS has released the wrong version of this component

Comment: I have same problem. Did you fix it ?

Comment: Install standalone git and check that the PATH variable is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening a command window and running the "git clone ..... " command. If it works, that definitely means it's not a proxy/firewall issue, and more likely an issue with Git and VS.

To fix that, I downloaded the standalone git installer [(downloader here)](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and it worked for me.

Comment: I've added more detail to my original question after running the commands at a prompt. Do you think installing the GIT client will be a workaround?

Comment: @David Possibly. They mentioned on that link that VS uses a cut-down version of git, so a full version might just work.

Comment: Followed instructions here to install GIT client and it has allowed me to work around the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538406/4186852

Comment: Of course you also need to tell VS to use the external git. That can be done in the VS options, David's link provides more to this.

Answer (score 10):

Dont know why this happens but this is how i solved it :

- **Install** standalone Git from http://git-scm.com/
- **Open** bash and **execute** to use https instead on git (firewall maybe blocking git protocol) :

  `git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`
- **Configure** Visual studio to use this new git tool instead :

  [image]
  just **add** the last line and **uncheck** the old git command line.

hope this helps