# bower.json not working in MVC6 Core 1.0 project (VS2015 2)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bower, asp.net-core-1.0

I haven't had this problem until recently and I want to make sure it isn't something on my end.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application project in VS2015.
2. Click show all files and open bower.json.
3. Change the version of bootstrap to version 3.3.6 and save the file.

You will see at the bottom of the screen that it says:

'An error occured installing packages. See output windows for details.'

I noticed that if you try changing any of the default versions this error appears.

Additionally there is no intellisense working for the version #'s after the ':' I just see a '*'.

The only thing I can think of is that ReSharper is interfering with it...

Please let me know if anyone else is having this issue with the latest version of VS2015 Community Update 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. (A big pain)
Try installing "Git" with second option. Just go to the Git download website and install it, but be careful with choosing configuration while installing. Add the git commands to the windows command path (You will find this option at last step of installation).

You can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902970/4082972

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can confirm that ReSharper has nothing to do with the problem. It is a VS2015 Update 2 bug. Installing git to your machine and starting VS will resolve the issue. Please update your post for others.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by pawan nepal didn't solve your problem run the following command in commmand prompt

git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://